# Building for iOS simulator Library issue

Tags: xcode, simulator, sqlcipher

I have an app that uses sqlcipher encryption, and with the latest release of Xcode I haven't been able to to run on simulator, I always get the following error.

```
Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked library 'libsqlcipher.a' was built for iOS.
```

I have researched that this error may be connected with Apple wishing us that move from .framework to .xcframework.

The open source of this library doesn't offer a .xcframwork. And I'm not sure I can build it locally.

I would like to ask if there is any workaround that can be done without having to purchase sqlcipher.